# Python script for creating envelope polygons for feature classes?

Tags: python, arcpy

I'm trying to write a script that creates an envelope polygon feature for an existing feature class that contains multiple features. The output needs to be a single envelope polygon for all features combined instead of one polygon for each individual feature.

The output should consist of a new feature class with a single envelope polygon for the entire feature class, not a polygon for each feature. The output can be a shapefile or a geodatabase feature class. I also need to work with just the input feature class and/or the geometries of the input features. The script should also be able to work on any feature class (geometry type, coordinate system, etc.)

I've been using a shapefile that represents the Hawaii islands for testing.

This is my code so far:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/Shapefiles"
fc = "hawaii.shp"
ofc = "hawaii_env"

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, "SHAPE@") as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        print(row[0].extent)
        polygon = [arcpy.Polygon(arcpy.Array(
        [arcpy.Point(row[0].extent.XMin, row[0].extent.YMin), arcpy.Point(row[0].extent.XMax, row[0].extent.YMin),
         arcpy.Point(row[0].extent.XMax, row[0].extent.YMax), arcpy.Point(row[0].extent.XMin, row[0].extent.YMax)]))]

arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(polygon, ofc)
```

When I run the script, the shapefile it produces is just one polygon, but I don't believe it is working correctly. The one polygon is only covering one island of hawaii. I'm not sure of the exact output I should receive and what to look for in ArcGIS Pro.

Any code to try or advice would be very helpful, thank you

Comment: Right, this is because you overwrite the `polygon` variable during each row, so when you exit the loop, you only have the last one.  I don't know how you concatenate two polygons in that package, but that's what you need to do -- each loop needs to attach the new polygon to the existing one, like appending to a list.

Answer (score 1):

This should be treated as a list of polygons, instead of overwriting the `polygon` variable in each round of a loop and finally getting a result only for the last polygon.

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/Shapefiles"

fc = "hawaii.shp"
ofc = "hawaii_env.shp"

polygons = []

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, "SHAPE@") as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        print(row[0].extent)
        polygons.append(
            arcpy.Polygon(arcpy.Array([
                arcpy.Point(row[0].extent.XMin, row[0].extent.YMin),
                arcpy.Point(row[0].extent.XMax, row[0].extent.YMin),
                arcpy.Point(row[0].extent.XMax, row[0].extent.YMax),
                arcpy.Point(row[0].extent.XMin, row[0].extent.YMax)
            ]))
        )

arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(polygons, ofc)
```